# How to show that a convex set is bounded

Tags: convex-analysis

Let A be a convex subset of $$R^{2}$$ containing the origin and possessing the following property: given any constants $$\alpha_{1}, \alpha_2\in R$$ such that $$\vert \alpha_1 \vert + \vert \alpha_2 \vert > 0,$$ the subset $$\{ (t \alpha_1,t\alpha_2 )\in R^2 ;t\geq0\}$$  contains at least one point that does not belong to A. How to show that A is bounded?

Comment: Just a thought - show that you can trap the set by a circle.

Comment: You are missing the condition that $A$ is closed, otherwise, the claim is false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Do you have a counter-example when $A$ is not closed?

Comment: A counter example is $\{(x,y): x>0,\ y>x^2\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: @Ruy, Ah, that makes sense. I was thinking about the case where $0$ is an interior point of $A$.

Comment: If 0 is assumed to be an interior point, then the question is a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172568/if-a-convex-set-s-subseteq-rn-contains-no-ray-can-you-show-that-its-bounde) (in view of the accepted answer). However, what's missing in the question is OP's thoughts and attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and unbounded, it always contains a ray, The ray need not be based at the origin, of course (hence the deletion of my incorrect answer).

Comment: @copper.hat: This is what's proven in the answer to the question I linked above.

Comment: **To OP:** Welcome to math.SE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It is a standard result in convex analysis, see Rockafellar's Convex Analysis Theorem 8.4, for example (it deals with a closed convex set, but $A$ is bounded **iff** $\overline{A}$ is bounded).

Comment: @copper.hat: of course.

Comment: @MoisheKohan.  The proof in the answer you linked to may be easily adapted to prove the present question, without the assumption that 0 is an interior point, but assuming the convex set is closed.  Actually the proof becomes even simpler as it is obvious that $Rx$ (see notation there) is in the convex set.

Comment: I find it very hard justifying a vote to close a question with so much activity!

Comment: @Ruy: In the case when $0$ is an interior point, you do not have to *adopt* the linked proof, it goes through verbatim. The closed case is, of course, easy as well. As for your last comment, read [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686487/to-show-a-closed-convex-set-s-subseteq-rn-is-bounded-if-and-only-if-s-cont?noredirect=1&lq=1 is much clearer than the one above, as it does not discuss interior points (which is not necessary). vote to close

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To show a closed convex set $S \subseteq R^n$ is bounded if and only if $S$ contains no rays.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686487/to-show-a-closed-convex-set-s-subseteq-rn-is-bounded-if-and-only-if-s-cont)

Answer (score 0):

How about the set
$\{(x, y) | (x \ge 0) \land (|y| \le \sqrt{x})\}
$?

This is convex
and
all lines through the origin
with non-zero slope
eventually leave the set.

Comment: I guess your set contains the infinite ray $\{(t,0):t\geq 0\}$.

Comment: But as you point out, $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2 = 0$ doesn't satisfy OP's conditions, right?

Comment: True. This shows that that condition is necessary.